# How would I morph two illustrated shapes in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, adobe-after-effects, animate

I'm trying to animate a logo (left) in AE and want it to end up like the one on the right. I created these in AI and copy/pasted them straight from AI instead of importing each artboard. I've tried using Bezier Path but it morphs the top right anchor point all the way down, and changing the entire shape instead of just adding the little triangle.  Is there a way to select the specific anchor points being changed to change them manually, or is there a better way to morph these shapes entirely? Thanks in advance for the help. I used this process (https://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/shape-morphing-with-after-effects) but it did not work for me. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem could come from the two paths not having the same number of anchor points.

Try creating the left shape by making a copy of the right shape and moving the lower right anchor point up.

This should make it possible for After Effects to guess what you are trying to do.